# How to change text color of picker view in swift?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Been trying to find an answer but can't find a genuine answer.
Thanks in advance. -Tom

Comment: Who ever downvoted this question, please tell me why you downvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Add bellow Delegate method of UIPickerView

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Your string name here", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
        return attributedString
    }
```

Comment: It's a `UIPickerViewDelegate` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attributedTitleForRow](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614375-pickerview) to set an attributed string. In the attributed string you can define the text color.